# spring boot jar not picking profile specific properties outside jar

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot jar(name : myjar) located in the directory structure

D:/hello/myjar

The fat jar contains profile specific application.properties in src/main/resources for e.g. application-local.properties

I want to override the attributes defined in the application-local.properties inside the jar with application-local.properties outside the jar

Hence I created application-local.properties and kept it in the same folder as jar i.e. D:/hello

However when I run my jar using the command :

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local D:/hello/myjar.jar
```

it still picks the properties which is inside the jar. Am I missing something ?

Comment: your command looks fine, try with `java -jar D:\hello\myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=local --spring.config.location=D:\hello`

Comment: no luck, it still picks the application-local.properties which are inside fat jar. There is some missing link for sure. I want the jar to pick the properties file which are outside jar.

Answer (score 3):

Try this use -D before -jar

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar  D:/hello/myjar.jar
```

let's see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: thanks! but I got the answer. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was more of point that from where I was running my jar from the command prompt.

If I run the jar from the folder where my jar is present, it does picks the profile specific files present outside the jar.